# Update Excel VLOOKUP based on newest file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file, automatically generated each morning with a generic name (Filename_YYYYMMDD).

Also I have an `XLSM` file that contains `vlookup` targeted to the above mentioned generic file.

In a macro, I would like to update the `vlookup` to point to the NEWEST file automatically created. Newest can mean either with the biggest date in the file name or the freshest creation date in the file properties. It should check either of the two parameters, change the file name in the `vlookup` formula and then automatically spread the formula to the whole column. The spreading part i can handle, but the date-change part I can not figure out.

Help?

Here is the `vlookup`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(H2=1;VLOOKUP(D2;'c:\path\[Filename_20130719.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$P;15;FALSE);G2);0)
```

Comment: you mentioned a macro - please paste it into the question

Comment: can you not replace the date with date function?

Comment: @mehow - did not even think of something like that... since i always "do" the table on the same day automatic one is created, it should really be easy... will try it out after my lunch break :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the date then you can use the replace method.
Something like:

`Columns("A").Replace What:="20130719", Replacement:="20130720", LookAt:=xlPart`

The catch is you always have to know the current date in the formula and the next date you want to replace.